# Referential Integrity constraint meaning

Tags: database

I was having a slight confusion regarding the meaning of referential integrity constraint:

Lets say I have two tables:

R1=(A,B,C)
R2=(D,E)

Then if I have C as a foreign key in R1 referring to R2.Lets say that the table R1 contains three records and attribute C refers to D(since D is primary key).So is it possible that the attribute D in table R2,apart from the records from attribute C in table R1 contains some other values as well?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's common.

Imagine, for example, that R<sub>2</sub> contains one row for each state in your country, and that R<sub>1</sub> contains rows that represent sales. And imagine further that you've sold things in only two or three states.